# What triggers an implicit call to paint() for a component in AWT?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I was reading through this:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#triggers

And it mentions the following:

> In a system-triggered painting operation, the system requests a
>   component to render its contents, usually for one of the following
>   reasons:
>
> - The component is first made visible on the screen.
> - The component is resized.
> - The component has damage that needs to be repaired. (For
>     example, something that previously obscured the component has moved,
>     and a previously obscured portion of the component has become
>     exposed).

The first point is fairly obvious. However, the second and third points leave something to be desired when determining if I need to call repaint(). Almost any example I see calls repaint() whenever a component's graphical properties change at all. However, there is some indication that if I change certain properties I shouldn't have to call repaint(). What might those properties be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a method that changes a property of the component that affects the way the component will be painted, then that method should invoke repaint(), not the application code. That is the repainting should be hidden from the programmer.

I don't understand what you mean by changing the clipping of the panel. Clipping is something that is done during the painting process. So if you have a property that affects the way you want the painting to be done, you invoke the method that changes that property, that method invokes repaint() and if the clipping area has changed, then your painting routine will use that information while doing the painting.

Comment: What I meant is the clipping on a graphic drawn on the JPanel. So not the JPanel itself.

Comment: @BrianReindel, still don't understand. Clipping is done when a component is repainted. This is easily tested. Do you get the desired results? Post a `SSCCE` if you don't.

Comment: I think the clipping example was a bad one. I'm mostly concerned with when I should call repaint(), and when AWT is going to call paint() for me. A better way to ask is, using the bullet points above, what would constitute a "resize" for a component?

Comment: A resize is when the frame resizes. Then all components on the frame are automatically repainted after all the layout manager has been invoked on the components. All this is done automatically the Swing RepaintManager. If your programming code invokes a `setXXX(...)`, then that method is responsible for invoking repaint() if the property changed affects the painting of the component.

Comment: I think your last comment best answers the question I was asking, so I've accepted your answer.